# Caching in Joomla

Tags: php, caching, joomla

I have a website in Joomla.

I had installed "Blank Module" in it and written my own code for user registration and login in a "Blank Module" php option.

The module was then added to the website.

When i enable caching "Global->System->Cache" to ON, the login process stops working. If i disable Cache, login works.

I am assuming the problem is because cache files get included after i try to login using my custom script.
Here is the code i have written:

```
if(isset($_POST['loginUser'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $mainframe->login($credentials);
}
```

Is there any way to first open caching and then start login process?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Vitul Goyal**,

- You need to simply disable the cache for that specific module.
- You can find it in first tab "Module" when you open your module from Joomla! Module Manager.
- Parameter name is "Caching" and you should select "No caching" and then save your changes.

Let me know if it works for you or not because there are many things can affect the caching of joomla page.

Thanks,
Mrunal.